# Simulink performance with S-Function

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am trying to run my simulink file which have pid controller connected to s-function block.

When i set three values parameters of pid  which are proportional, integral and derivatives it takes too long to run the whole process. Why this is happened?

In the dialog box of my pid diagram, for porportional value, its equal to the value which correspond to the constant amplitude oscillation.

Then for integral, its equal to Kcu/Ti. Ti is the ultimate period(Pu)/2 and

lastly for derivatives, its equal tu Kcu*Td and Td is Pu /8. This is refer to ziegler nichols method. and again my question is why it takes too long to running this file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB S-functions are slow because they run in the MATLAB interpreter. Consider implementing it using Simulink blocks or using a "Embedded MATLAB Function" (pre-R2011a) or "MATLAB Function" (R2011a+) block.

Read [Guy](http://blogs.mathworks.com/seth/2010/10/28/tips-for-simulation-performance/) and [Seth](http://blogs.mathworks.com/seth/2010/12/06/5-resources-for-simulation-performance/)'s thoughts on Simulation performance.

Answer (score 1):

@Nzbuu is right about the Matlab S-functions.

But I think the problem here could be somewhere else: @Syarina are you saying that the Simulink simulation gets slower **after** you set the proportional coefficient for the controller? If you simulate the plant alone, in this case the S-function, do you notice a significant difference in the execution speed? If it is really so, I suppose the PID controller makes the ODE system [stiff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiff_equation). This means that the different states of the ODE system have really different dynamics - some are very fast, some are very slow. Using an ode-solver that is not suited for stiff equations you will find the simulation much slower (actually you would have luck if it converges at all).

My suggestion is try to change the solver - for example [ode15s](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/f11-69449.html).

Comment: yes sir.thank you.before this i used ode45.then after change to ode15, its running more faster.thanks